Calculating phase margin for compensated operational amplifier
I have come across this article: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/input-capacitance-analog-circuits-how-to-compensate-capacitance-op-amps/
It describes compensating for an op-amp's input capacitance using the feedback capacitor Cf. There are two targets described: phase margin PM = 90° and PM = 45°. I am puzzled by what seems to be a small discrepancy in the latter - PM is found to be 58.8° instead of 45°. This 58.8° figure is verified by a calculation:

Where did the shift from 45° to 58.8° occur between deriving Eq. 10 for Cf for PM = 45° and getting PM = 58.8° according to Eq. 7 and Eq. 6?
